# Как совместить 2 блока в один

Tags: javascript

Как совместить 2 блока в один по содержанию, как показано в примере, в блоках с классом index есть первые div-ы с одинаковой информацией, нужно сделать так, чтобы все такие одинаковые по первому диву блоки совмещались в 1

```html
<div>

  <div class="index1">
    <div>
      <p>cont</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information1.0</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information1.2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="index2">
    <div>
      <p>cont</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information2.0</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information2.2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="index3">
    <div>
      <p>payment</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information3.0</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information3.2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

итог:

```html
<div>

  <div class="index1">
    <div>
      <p>cont</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information1.0</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information1.2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information2.0</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information2.2</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="index3">
    <div>
      <p>payment</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information3.0</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>information3.2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div
```

Comment: Изначально задумка не верная, формировать меню или кааие то блоки надо уже на js и уже на js выводить их и наполнять информацией

Comment: Иначе это лишняя нагрузка...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил для наглядности пару блоков:

```js
function FusionBySameCaption(selector) {
  let children = document.querySelector(selector).parentElement.children;
  let index = 0;
  while (index < children.length) {
    let child = children[index];
    let text = child.querySelector('div:first-of-type > p').textContent;
    let i = index++;
    while (children[++i]) {
      let sibling = children[i];
      if (text == sibling.querySelector('div:first-of-type > p').textContent) {
        sibling.firstElementChild.remove();
        child.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', sibling.innerHTML);
        sibling.remove();
        i--;
      }
    }
  }
}

FusionBySameCaption('[class^="index"]');
```

```css
/* For example only --> */ [class^="index"]{margin:8px 0;padding:1px;box-shadow:0 0 2px 2px #f00}[class^="index"] p{margin:1px;box-shadow:inset 0 0 2px 2px #00f}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="index5">
    <div><p>test</p></div>
    <div><p>information 5.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 5.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index1">
    <div><p>cont</p></div>
    <div><p>information 1.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 1.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index3">
    <div><p>payment</p></div>
    <div><p>information 3.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 3.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index2">
    <div><p>cont</p></div>
    <div><p>information 2.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 2.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index4">
    <div><p>payment</p></div>
    <div><p>information 4.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 4.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index6">
    <div><p>test</p></div>
    <div><p>information 6.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 6.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index7">
    <div><p>test</p></div>
    <div><p>information 7.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 7.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index8">
    <div><p>test</p></div>
    <div><p>information 8.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 8.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index9">
    <div><p>test</p></div>
    <div><p>information 9.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 9.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index10">
    <div><p>payment</p></div>
    <div><p>information 10.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 10.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index11">
    <div><p>payment</p></div>
    <div><p>information 11.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 11.2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index12">
    <div><p>cont</p></div>
    <div><p>information 12.0</p></div>
    <div><p>information 12.2</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: После совмещения 3 блоков, он начинает делать следующий блок с таким же названием

Comment: @user480491: исправил. Проверьте.

Comment: Все отлично работает, спасибо за помощь